# Is there a way to auto-generate or at least shorten (some parameter like __all__) the serialize function?

Tags: c++, boost, automation, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I am dealing with a network where messages(request as well as responses) are transferred as structs. For achieving this, I turned to boost-serialization, which works great! but with so many types of messages and responses, it's hard to include the serialize function in all of them, is there a shortcut to auto generate the method for all structs or at least exposing every member variable at once?

**Example:**

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
struct Test
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        template<typename archive> void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned version) {
        ar & a; 
        ar & b;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I answered this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195562/85371):

```
struct Test {
    int a,b;
    template<typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & a & b; }
};
```

Note that if you make serialize a free function as well (ADL lookup is used):

```
struct Test {
    int a,b;
};

template<typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Test& o, unsigned) {
    ar & o.a & o.b;
}
```

So you can have the serialization code separately. Finally, if you have a predefined set of archives the serialize function doesn't need to be a template at all:

```
using OArchive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive;
using IArchive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive;

struct Test {
    int a,b;
    void serialize(OArchive& ar, ...) const { ar & a & b; }
    void serialize(IArchive& ar, ...)       { ar & a & b; }
};
```

Of course this creates some duplication. I got cute to ignore the version argument with variadics, but on the flip size it's more `const`-correct.

### Other thoughts

If your structs are binary serializable, mark them as such:

- [Boost serialization bitwise serializability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121545/boost-serialization-bitwise-serializability/28123893#28123893)
- Or explicitly treat them as blobs: [`make_binary_object`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#binaryobjects) - in this case you don't need any serialization methods:

  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d8f0f1a137ce4da)**

  ```
  #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
  #include <iostream>
  using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

  struct Test { int a,b; };

  int main() {
      boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout, boost::archive::no_header);

      Test req {13,31};
      oa << make_binary_object(&req, sizeof(req));
  }
  ```

  Prints

  ```
  DQAAAB8AAAA=
  ```

### META-PROGRAMMING TO THE RESCUE

> Fair warning, as a C programmer you probably want to bail out and just use more preprocessor magic/code generators here

Say you have more messages (which can nest):

```
namespace Messages {
    struct FooMsg { int a, b; };
    struct BarMsg { std::string c; double d; };
    struct QuxMsg { FooMsg e; BarMsg f; };
}
```

You can adapt these as [Fusion Sequences](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence.html):

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::FooMsg, a, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::BarMsg, c, d)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::QuxMsg, e, f)
```

The good thing is now you can write generic code across these sequences, so let's introduce our very own [serialization wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html):

```
namespace Messages {
    template <typename T>
    struct MsgSerializationWrapper {
        T& ref;
    };

    template <typename T>
    static inline MsgSerializationWrapper<T> wrap(T& msg) { return {msg}; }
```

Now you can implement serialization for any wrapped message:

```
    template <typename Ar, typename Msg>
    void serialize(Ar& ar, MsgSerializationWrapper<Msg> wrapped, unsigned) {
        boost::fusion::for_each(wrapped.ref, [&ar](auto& field) { ar & wrap(field); });
    }
```

Of course, we need some sfinae to detect when the wrapped type is not a fusion sequence and just serialize that the normal way.

#### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/470f7390a67aaded)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace Messages {
    struct FooMsg { int a, b; };
    struct BarMsg { std::string c; double d; };
    struct QuxMsg { FooMsg e; BarMsg f; };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::FooMsg, a, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::BarMsg, c, d)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Messages::QuxMsg, e, f)

namespace Messages {
    template <typename T>
    struct MsgSerializationWrapper {
        T& ref;
    };

    template <typename T>
    static inline MsgSerializationWrapper<T> wrap(T& msg) { return {msg}; }

    template <typename Ar, typename Msg>
    std::enable_if_t<boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<Msg>::value>
    serialize(Ar& ar, MsgSerializationWrapper<Msg> wrapped, unsigned) {
        boost::fusion::for_each(wrapped.ref, [&ar](auto& field) { ar & wrap(field); });
    }

    template <typename Ar, typename Primitive>
    std::enable_if_t<not boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<Primitive>::value>
    serialize(Ar& ar, MsgSerializationWrapper<Primitive> wrapped, unsigned) {
        ar & wrapped.ref;
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);

    Messages::QuxMsg req { 
        Messages::FooMsg { 42, 99 },
        Messages::BarMsg { "hello world\n", 3.14e100 },
    };

    oa << wrap(req);
}
```

Prints

```
22 serialization::archive 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 42 99 0 0 0 0 12 hello world
 0 0 3.13999999999999984e+100
```

Comment: Added hints on (non portable) bitwise/binary object serialization

Comment: Answered the broader question with some meta-programming as well: META-PROGRAMMING TO THE RESCUE ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/470f7390a67aaded))

Comment: Thanks for such a informative answer, not only it answers my question but also provides alternatives.